# Symfony2 : how to force download

Tags: symfony, download

I am trying to make a link to download a file with symfony2. It does download a file, but it's useless as it is zero octect. I don't know how to make it work. Does anybody know how to do?

The file is in `web/uploads/documents/`.

Here is the code in the controller:

```
// here I get the name of the file

  $response = new Response();
  $response->headers->set('Content-type', 'application/octet-stream');
  $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', sprintf('attachment; filename="%s"', $filename));

  return $response;
```

I tried to write the whole path instead of `$filename` but it changes all the slashes in underscore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to set the content:

```
$response->setContent(file_get_contents($localFilePath));
```